# Find, Replace Scenarios

Tags: excel

[image]

I'm trying to have my departments all follow the same syntax.  This column is a mess and I'm try to match all of them together.
So Line 1.. 0948209-HR is the ideal example.
How do I make it so we perform a look up to see if the department matches another department's code (so in this case it would match Line 1), to take that department ID and replace it with the current one for 2?

So in other words I want to turn "948209" to "0948209-HR" based on a match within a lookup.

Also, how do I take out leading spaces in between the dashes for "0381401 - Information Services) (Line 3)

Comment: I believe this is the task which involves Visual Basic coding. I'm not sure if you can make such changes using plain Excel function mechanism. Maybe with macros, but I'm inexperienced in that matter.

Comment: My opinion you would separate the two pieces into two cells with a vlookup  in the second, so all they do is put in a number and the vlookup will put the words in the second cell.  Then you can put a data validation on the first column for only number and put a custom number format of `0000000`.  Then if they do not put the leading 0 excel will put it in for them.

Comment: I agree with @ScottCraner and you could even go as far as adding a dropdown to the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution that involves a few changes to your current worksheet.

First, create a lookup table for your departments:

Within the lookup table, use `=TEXT("department code","0000000")` to ensure your department codes maintain their leading zeros (see `Column E`).

Then use `=CONCATENATE(E2,"-",F2)` to form the full name (see `Column G`).

[image: table]
[image: table]

We will now bounce against the lookup table to return the Department Name and Code.  The result is in `Column B`.

[image: table]

Assuming your data begins in `A2` (and your data table is in the same location as this example), enter `=VLOOKUP(LEFT(TEXT(A2,"0000000"),7),$E$2:$G$3,3,0)` in `B2` and drag down.

[image: table]